# Selenium IDE opens a new window

Tags: selenium-ide

We have a button on the website that should open a modal (only).

Selenium IDE is opening the modal AND additionally a new blank window.

This is the command I am using to click:

```
<td>clickAt</td>
<td>css=#tabControl .settings</td>
```

though when clicking manually on the same button (I mean manually in the browser), this doesn't happen, instead it opens just the modal.
A similar issue happens when it should open a link in a new tab, it opens it in a new window instead.
Also I see this error:

[warn] Link has target '_blank', which is not supported in Selenium! Randomizing target to be: selenium_blank19992

Two questions:

1. Is there a way that it will not open the new window at all?
2. if no, is it possible to close that new window? I managed to close windows with the "SelectWindow" and then "Close" commands, but the problem with this one is that it doesn't have any title, so I cannot select it and when I am just using "Close", it closes the wrong window..

Thanks

Comment: You should have a read through this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target

Comment: Ok, I read it.. and? :) Sorry, I don't see what am I suppose to get out of it. 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: `target="_blank"`: "Load the response into a new unnamed HTML4 window or HTML5 browsing context."

Comment: Ok.. and? My issue is that is that in all the browsers (including FF) clicking on this action will open it in a new tab, but when clicking on the same thing via Selenium IDE it will open an additional blank window. So issue is specifically with how Selenium IDE behaves

Answer (score 0):

Your code is saying find the item with the id of 'tabControl' and 'clickAt' every descendant of that item that has the class 'settings'.

```
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>css=#tabControl.settings</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: @VladiTrop You need to remove the space between Control and .settings.

Comment: @VladiTrop the space means to look for descendants

Comment: @VladiTrop actually, .settings shouldn't be needed at all.

Comment: hm.. there are 3 buttons under #tabControl and .settings is the descendant of the #tabControl. If I do inspect element this is the correct class. Also when I record that's the  class it shows. Also if I remove the space it doesn't find the object on the page then..

Comment: @VladiTrop ohh okay, then yes leave it... just so you know, Selenium will record it as it sees fit, that doesn't mean its the only way nor the best way to select it.